# SQL with if condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to run the following query on both MYSQL and MSSQL. I want to check whether `CHECKTIME >= 12` from `CHECKINOUT` table and insert it in to the `Att_process` table's `checkout_time` field if this condition is true.

```
INSERT INTO Att_process(USERID,checkout_time)
SELECT CHECKINOUT.USERID,CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME
from CHECKINOUT 
where DATEPART(HOUR,CHECKTIME) >= 12;
```

How can I create a trigger like this on both MySQL and MSSQL?

[image: Table image]

Comment: I removed the "mysql" tag because `datepart()` is a SQL Server function.  You should also try formatting your question better.  One hint is not to use so many capital letters.

Comment: Try and read and understand what you've written. Does it make any sense? (And, SO is not a code-writing service.)

Comment: What's the specific problem you have when writing the triggers? What did you try?

Comment: Actually I dont Know how to create Triggers on Ms sql and my sql,so i want to process That query on a trigger Both Ms sql and My sql Because i  have My data base on Ms sql and My sql,I have a finger print machine,it's download data to Ms sql, i am syschronize that data to My sql data base that's why i need both triggers to process attendance data,So can you help me to do that

Comment: if (DATEPART(HOUR,CHECKTIME) < 12 )
BEGIN

INSERT INTO Att_process(USERID,checkin_time)
SELECT CHECKINOUT.USERID,CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME
from CHECKINOUT 
where DATEPART(HOUR,CHECKTIME) < 12; 
END
ELSE
BEGIN

INSERT INTO Att_process(USERID,checkout_time)
SELECT CHECKINOUT.USERID,CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME
from CHECKINOUT 
where DATEPART(HOUR,CHECKTIME) >= 12;
END- can you tell me is there any error on this query please